# Trim specific character from beginning and end of string

Tags: php

I just wondered if there was a more efficient way of removing a comma (if there is one) from the beginning and end of a string?

```
if (substr($_SESSION['login_dashboard'], 0, 1)==",") $_SESSION['login_dashboard'] = substr($_SESSION['login_dashboard'], 1);
if (substr($_SESSION['login_dashboard'], -1, 1)==",") $_SESSION['login_dashboard'] = substr($_SESSION['login_dashboard'], 0, -1);
```

Comment: You could use trim() if you not only want to remove the first and last comma, but all commas at the beginning and end.

Comment: Thanks, I never realised Trim would trim anything other than spaces!

Comment: The second parameter of trim() is a character mask, so you can specify your own characters. But as I said this is slightly different to your current method. string: `,,string,,` your method output: `,string,` trim output: `string`

Comment: Downvoted to all answers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
$myStr = 'planes,trains,automobiles,';
$myStr = trim($myStr, ',');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$char = ",test,test2,test3,";
echo trim($char,',');
```

output is

test,test2,test3

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use `trim()` function:

```
echo trim($_SESSION['login_dashboard'],',');
```